# How to rotate bits in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am trying to create a way to rotate bits in Verilog according to a calculated register.

Here is what I have tried:

`temp_1 = (temp_2 << bits_to_rotate) | (temp_2 >> ~bits_to_rotate);`

Where the variables are defined as:

```
integer bits_to_rotate = 3;
reg [0:7] temp_1;
initial temp_1 = 0; 
reg [0:7] temp_2;
initial temp_2 = 8'b1100010;
```

[image]

This command is currently only shifting the input and adding zeros on the end. How can I rotate the bits and not add zeros on the end?

Comment: Why not `temp_1 = {temp_2[n-1:0], temp_2[N:n]};`?

Comment: @ThePhoton What is n and N? Also if I use that then I get an error saying that the bit range must be bounded by a constant

Answer (score 2):

The left shift term (`<<`) in your expression behaves as you expect.  It shifts all 8 bits to the left by 3 positions, dropping the 3 MSB's and adding 3 `0` bits to the LSB's.  This gives you `8'b0001_0000`.

However, the right shift term (`>>`) does not behave as you expect.  It will always return 8 `0` bits: `8'b0000_0000`.  Then when you bitwise OR your 2 terms, you are only left with the left-shift term.  The expression `~bits_to_rotate` is evaluated by first expanding `bits_to_rotate` to 8 bits before the bitwise negation operator (`~`) is applied.  3 is evaluated as `8'b0000_0011`, which when negated is `8'b1111_1100`, which is decimal 252.  This means your are right-shifting by 252 bits.  For any value of `bits_to_rotate` from 0 to 7, `~bits_to_rotate` will always be larger than 8.

What you want to do is to shift right by 5 bits (8-3=5): `(8 - bits_to_rotate)`.  This will shift all 8 bits to the right by 5 positions, dropping the 5 LSB's and adding 5 `0` bits to the MSB's.  This gives you `8'b0000_0011`.  Then, when you do the bitwise OR of the 2 terms, you get: `8'b0001_0000 | 8'b0000_0011 = 8'b0001_0011`.

Change:

```
temp_1 = (temp_2 << bits_to_rotate) | (temp_2 >> ~bits_to_rotate);
```

to:

```
temp_1 = (temp_2 << bits_to_rotate) | (temp_2 >> (8-bits_to_rotate));
```

See also [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Circular_shift).

Here is a complete code example:

```
module tb;

integer bits_to_rotate;
reg [0:7] temp_1;
reg [0:7] temp_2;

initial begin
    temp_1 = 0; 
    temp_2 = 8'b0110_0010;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
        bits_to_rotate = i;
        temp_1 = (temp_2 << bits_to_rotate) | (temp_2 >> (8-bits_to_rotate));
        $display("%0d", bits_to_rotate);
        $display("%08b", temp_2);
        $display("%08b", temp_1);
        $display;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
0
01100010
01100010

1
01100010
11000100

2
01100010
10001001

3
01100010
00010011

4
01100010
00100110

5
01100010
01001100

6
01100010
10011000

7
01100010
00110001
```

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the shifting right part is not `~bits_to_rotate`. It should be `$bits(temp_2) - bits_to_rotate`

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to port some of my VHDL 2008 code to SystemVerilog and run into the same problem of there being no built-in rotate.

The following seems to work,

```
   parameter int g_num_irq    = 32
        . . . . .
   input     logic   [g_num_irq - 1:0]    i_arb_req,
        . . . . .
   typedef  logic    [$clog2(g_num_irq) - 1:0]  t_arb_sel;
        . . . . .
   t_arb_sel         s_rot_sel;
        . . . . .
                       // Rotate right
    for (ix = 0; ix < $bits(s_arb_req); ix++) 
       s_arb_req[ix]  <= s_arb_req_in[(ix + s_rot_sel) % $bits(s_arb_req)];
    
        . . . . .
                         // Rotate left
    for (ix = 0; ix < $bits(s_arb_grant_out); ix++) 
       s_arb_grant_out[(ix + s_rot_sel) % $bits(s_arb_grant_out)]    <= s_arb_grant[ix];
```

A summary simulation does what it is supposed to do, synthesis doesn't complain either.

Really annoying though that SystemVerilog synthesisable syntax won't allow this to be put in a package for use with vectors of random length.